# Azure ML Studio: How to import images dataset?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, dataset, image-recognition, azure-machine-learning-service

In Azure ML studio, how to import images dataset, for image recognition algorithms. As zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "**import images**" module in Azure ML Studio that can read images from Azure blob storage - [here](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Face-detection-2) is the sample experiment

Comment: I think your answer might be better than the answer of the support team, i have to test it though

Comment: import images only works with module "pretrained cascade image classification module". if you need to use your own algorithm, then support team's answer is correct - here is sample that uses the technique suggested by support team - https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Compare-Multi-class-Classifiers-Letter-recognition-2

Comment: thank you, for your help, I accepted your answer even if mine is correct, it's meaningless to accept my own answer in terms of rep, and you helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I just asked the support team in chat, they were super fast in replying

> 1. You could try converting your image into a format that the Studio
>      data upload tool understands (i.e. csv).
> 2. You can probably put the image file in a .zip file, upload that to
>      your workspace, and then manipulate this data file in an 'Execute R
>      Script". [An example](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/92bcba7c206649c2ab2152df916dd666?r=legacy) of first Option.